# yield return in Task<IEnumerable<string>>

Tags: c#, .net-core

How to use `yield return` when method's return-type is a Task, for example `Task<IEnumerable<string>>`?

This is my code:

```
    private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetNameAsync(List<MyEntity> entities)
    {
        List<string> finalstrings = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in entities)
        {
            finalstrings.Add(item.Name);
        }

        return finalstrings;
    }
```

I'm using dotnet core 3.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [page](https://anthonychu.ca/post/async-streams-dotnet-core-3-iasyncenumerable/) for how to do it.

Comment: Use `IAsyncEnumerable` instead, see the third answer in the linked duplicate question.